# concat the query into new line

Tags: php, sql

This is my code

```
select concat(ifnull(homeaddr1,''),' ', 
              ifnull(homeaddr2,''),' ',
              ifnull(homeaddr3,'')) as billaddr 
FROM Table
```

I always end up having this.

```
homeaddr1 homeaddr2 homeaddr3
```

Instead, I want them to be each address in next line like:

```
homeaddr1  
homeaddr2  
homeaddr3
```

Regards, Dumbest.

Comment: Worked fine for me! Nothing wrong with this query.

Comment: I need the homeaddr2 to be on the next line and the addr3 on the next line.

Comment: Are you showing this result in HTML or just want to have results in 3 rows by query itself?

Comment: i am need to put the 3 homeaddr into 1 variable and output them in that alignment in php.

Comment: 1/ Add the HTML in your concat OR 2/ Get an array with 3 row and in PHP make a foreach that echo each row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If going to output those in HTML/PHP then you should try:

```
concat(ifnull(homeaddr1,''),'\n', ifnull(homeaddr2,''),'\n',ifnull(homeaddr3,''))
```

Instead of:

```
concat(ifnull(homeaddr1,''),' ', ifnull(homeaddr2,''),' ',ifnull(homeaddr3,''))
```

Replace `' '` with `'\n'`.

Comment: Right. Query will be `select concat(ifnull(homeaddr1,''),'<br>', ifnull(homeaddr2,''),'<br>',ifnull(homeaddr3,'')) as billaddr FROM Table`

Comment: $que = "select concat(ifnull(homeaddr1,''),'<br>', ifnull(homeaddr2,''),'<br>',ifnull(homeaddr3,'')) as billaddr FROM Table"   

this is the whole query.

Comment: When you echo this with php it will show address in 3 separate lines.

Comment: I echoed it, this was the given output. "Tayag,<br>Bislig City,
Camarines Sur<br>(with"

Comment: Try using `\n` instead of `<br>` in query.

Comment: Thank you @Lovepreet  It worked. thak you very much.